# How do I theme a custom form?

Tags: theming, forms, 8, hooks

I generate a simple module "myformtest" with a simple Class form "MyformtestForm". I want to use a different theme for the form.

I followed this great [tutorial](https://www.foreach.be/blog/how-manipulate-forms-drupal-8). I added a "_theme_suggestions_alter" hook in my "myformtest.module", I activated twig debugging and I loaded the form page.

[image]

My "suggestion theme" is present and its name is "form--myformtest-form.html.twig". Then in my module directory:

- I added a sub-directory "templates"
- I added the twig file "form--myformtest-form.html.twig" in the sub-directory "drupal/modules/custom/myformtest/templates"

In the twig file, I added this simple code. (I copied it from the drupal/core/themes/classy/templates/form/form.html.twig and added the h1 html element for override)

```
<h1>TEST</h1>
<form{{ attributes }}>
    {{ children }}
</form>
```

I clear caches (drush cr) and I reloaded my form page. But the html element h1 ("TEST") doesn't appear! Where is my mistake?

**UP**

I did it ! I added the hook theme in my .module file :

```
function myformtest_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
  return array(
    'form__myformtest_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'form--myformtest-form',
    ),
  );
}
```

But.... ! When I load my form page, the html element h1 "test" is displayed but not the form :/ I thinked my .twig file override the form.html.twig default theme.

[image]

Did I miss something ? Why the form doesn't displayed, how can I fix it ? And how can I pass a custom array from my build method of form Class to my twig template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution :

I don't understand why copy and past the default form twig content doesn't work. (why attributes and children variables doesn't work)

I dumped all availables twig variables from my custom template (via {{ dump() }} ) . I see I had a array named "element"..I tried this and its work ! the form is displayed.

This is the code of my custom form template :

```
<h1>TEST</h1>
<form{{ element }}></form>
```

Comment: It should be like <form{{ attributes }}>{{ children }}</form>.

Comment: This answer is accepted, but it is not good. At the very least, it should have been `<form>{{ element }}</form>` (notice the `>`. There is a chance that that will work, because `element` may contain the contents of the form. but that is not how it's intended to work.

Answer (score 3):

I've just been encountering a similar problem. And solved it like following.

In my `MYMODULE.module` file:

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  return [
    'mythemename' => [
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'my-template-name',
    ],
  ];
}
```

In the `$form`:

```
$form['#theme'] = 'mythemename';
```

And finally in the `my-template-name.html.twig` template:

```
<div class="someclass">
  {{ form }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form element already has a base template.

To override the base template you will need to add twig file in your theme's templates directory.

*The template directory in modules exists to provide base templates.*

Comment: thanks for answer :) If I understand, I must add le suggest twig template in the theme's template directory (this can't work in module/templates dir). Can you detail what the template directory in module ? When you speak about "provide bas template", you mean I can only add in this dir bases templates (like form.html.twig by example?)

Comment: The template directory in modules exists to provide templates for new themes provided by the module. For example a template for a new type of field.

Comment: Ok, I see...but in the tutirial I linked in my initial post, its seems we can use the suggest template in the custom/mymodule/templates) , in the part 'Look & feel of the form' #4..

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like the tutorial is mistreating on this account.

Comment: The reason modules don't support this behavior is that in the end, only one template can be used. If you had multiple modules with the same template file name, which of the two should drupal chose?

Comment: I agree, but here, I created a template with a unique id (the name of the form), then Drupal will use this template only when the form concerned is loaded. So Drupal won't need choose because each twig Ill create will use unique name (the name of the form in each twig)

Comment: I did it ! Drupal use my template but.. only a label is displayed, not the form. I updated my initial post (see **UP** )

Comment: I always have issues using hook_theme() for this, now I more often use hook_theme_registry_alter() to set 'template', 'path' and 'preprocess functions'

Comment: please print {{form}} in your template

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to copy the content of form.html.twig file to your custom template. Then you can make further changes in your custom template. This way, your form should render on the page.

Comment: I thinked too :) I copied the content of the form.html.twik located from drupal/core/themes/classy/templates/form/form.html.twig to mymodule/templates/form--myformtest-form.twig (this is the code I showed in my initial post without the html h1 element). But the form doesn't show in my form page